# Select at runtime the field in a table with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, system.reflection

I'm trying to do a base class that makes all the CRUD in a generic way so I can derive classes for each table in my SQL Server database, using mainly those derived classes to check if the data that the user inserts is valid.

The problem I'm facing is that I can dynamically select the table (`datacontext_.GetTable<T>()`) and use it in the LINQ query but I can't find the way to do the proper `Select` or `Where` with reflection. All I need to find is the Id field in the table.

The method I want to create is something like:

```
Select(int id)
{
    T record = from db in myDataContext where db.Id == id select db;
    return record;
}
```

I've already tried:

- the `from...where...select` approach (as the example)
- `from...where...select` with reflection (`db.GetType().GetField("Id")`...)
- building the lambda with a procedure and passing it as a parameter to `.Where`
- `.Where(x=> x.Id == id)`
- `.Where(x=> x.GetType().GetField("Id").Equals(id))`

And all other variations of the reflection method I have found.

When I debug the program, the LINQ without the Where works (it shows the proof data in [0]) but the next step (Where) doesn't work regardless of the way I try.

It sure is some stupid point I'm missing (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a common interface and implement it all of your entity classes (they are all partial by design) like:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Then you can handle all implementation with a common way like with an extension method:

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static TEntity Select<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, int id) where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        return source.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

But i think it's not worth doing it becouse you would reinvent the wheel for no real reason.

Comment: That last sentence... how I have to do it "the proper way"? I really don't know it (I wish I did).